# Dynamic Updating

Tags: dynamic

My program runs for a while and then comes up with a notification telling"The Kernel is not responding to a dynamic evaluation.  You may either choose to abort and restart the kernel or continue waiting. Dynamic updating can be re enabled using the Dynamic updating Enabled command in the evaluation menu".I tried updating the Dynamic updating command.  But i still get the same notification.  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: _I tried updating the Dynamic updating command_ Do you mean _enabling_ Dynamic updating? What if on the contrary you do not tick it? The error should no longer appear (and of course the dynamic contents will no longer be dynamic...).

Comment: This sometimes happens to me when my computer is running short of memory due to a very memory-intensive Mathematica calculation.

Comment: @anderstood: Yes i mean enabling Dynamic updating.  I am trying to solve an transcendental equation and the equation contains another equation which needs to solved simultaneously.  For example my function look something like this                                                         
 f[x_] := ((b1[x] + (a1[x]*c1[x]))*d1[x])/((b2[x] + (a1[x]*c2[x]))*
    d2[x]) - ((b3[x] + (a1[x]*c3[x]))*d3[x])/((b4[x] + (a1[x]*c4[x]))*
    d4[x]);
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 1*10^(14) + i}]; a1[x] has to be equal to a2[x].  a1[x] and a2[x] are defined before.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific in your question and add a minimal working example showing the issue you are facing?

Comment: @anderstood As in the comments i was running short of memory...got it fixed...